# How to increase cassandra yaml file performance to have fast write query?

Tags: performance, cassandra

when i tried to insert one million rows of data in cassandra database such as i have performance hardware, take one minutes for insert it. Anyone can help me please how to increase settings by default of cassandra, i want exactlly what are the main parameteres wanto to modify in cassandra yaml file or cassandra-env file to have best performance to fit well with my server

i tried with using cql commands

CQL Command: Copy table_name(field1, ..., fieldn) to 'path_file'

9000 rows in seconds, 56 millions rows inserted in 54 minutes

Comment: That's copying OUT to a file, not into the database. Typically if you want faster performance you need to scale out with Cassandra. Each host can perform X I/O per second (based off I/O speed, cpu, etc). The math is somewhat straight-forward. You want to move faster than that, scale out. Hopefully your table model allows for scaling as well.

Comment: @JimWartnickv, just i forget the syntax, essential i use cql to copy from file to db. for you, how do you find this value (56 Millions in 54minuts) are you logic, you can give me please some approach about the rate insertion and thanks in advance, if you have any tutorial or book recommand it for me please

Comment: If you know the hardware - what types of devices (hopefully SSDs), you should be able to find the max IOPs and throughput of the device. It can't go faster than that. You can run "iostat" commands to watch the "test" - it will show you IOPs and throughput. Something like: " iostat -c -d -x -t -m -z 1 3600" to watch every 1 second for 3600 seconds (1 hour). Spool that to a file and watch it run. Now you're using a COPY command which may have it's own inefficiencies. You could code it yourself using asynchronous inserts - which is blazing fast. Or consider dsbulk if that's an option.

Comment: @JimWartnickv thank you verry much for you, i will test that